# Git commits are not using the repository-configured `user.name` value

Tags: git, git-config

I have a repository where I've configured a local `user.name` and `user.email`. I've verified this as running `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` within the git repo gives the right outputs, and my `.git/config` file shows them correctly as well - but my commits still use my global `user.name` (although they do use the correct local `user.email`). I am running macOS 10.13.4 and Git 2.17.1 - the issue happens both with command-line git and committing from IntelliJ. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `git config user.name` prints the correct name but `git commit` does not use that name, something must be overriding the configured value.

The obvious (cough) candidate is an [environment variable, as listed in the top level `git` command manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html), most of the way to the end.  You can do a quick test whether this is the case using [the `git var` command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-var.html):

```
$ git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | sed 's/@/ /'
Chris Torek <chris.torek gmail.com> 1528489689 -0700
```

vs:

```
$ GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='A U Thor' GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=thor@example.com git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT
A U Thor <thor@example.com> 1528489743 -0700
```

This shows how I overwrote the name and email address that *would* have come out, had I not set these environment variables.

Comment: Yep, it was this simple, I had `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` set!